# Should I implement matrix transformations over changing object coordinates?

Tags: graphics, transformation, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

I have a set of objects that can be scaled and translated.
Suppose the user selects an object and drag to some position.
I was thinking about implementing this in two different ways: either changing the coordinates of the objects given the mouse position, or changing the transformation matrix.
Is one of these implementations better than the other?
My main issues are:

- Performance
- Code organization
- Scalability

Answer (score 0):

Objects have certain coordinates, and the way you look at objects has a certain frame of reference. I think it is better not to mess with your coordinates, and instead to change just the matrix that takes you from "the object is here" to "I draw the object here". It is much cleaner. Performance wise you have to apply a transformation to each object being rendered, so you may as well do it just once.  From. Code organization perspective it is better to keep things "relating to something physical"; and from a scalability perspective, not applying a transformation to all objects every time the user changes the view is clearly preferable - you only apply the transformation to objects when you render them, so if you can't keep up you skip a step; if you didn't rescale some of your objects during each step you would quickly get into trouble. Finally, applying multiple transformations to the same object would tend to accumulate errors.

Stream of conscience, but clear preference,  I think!